# Upload sound file to the net to use withJavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html

How can I play sound when the mp3 file is in my computer?

How or where can I upload my sound file to the net and then to use the link in my code?
The sites that I tried gave me a link without the mp3 ending.

```
function play_sound() {
  var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
  audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sound.mp3');
  audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
  audioElement.load();
  audioElement.play();
}
play_sound();
```

Comment: Any webserver, some file hosting services...

Answer (score 0):

If when you click on the link, it start to download the mp3 file, it will work in your code even if it's not an mp3 extention.

Comment: and where can i upload it to get  a link and use it in  my code?

Comment: I can't tell any sites, I usually use my home server for that. But you already tried some sites, those should work.

Comment: audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://vocaroo.com/i/s1JRqxYv6jN1');              why its not working ? i chainged the sound.mp3 file to this link that i got and its not working

Comment: I don't think that you will be able to use this site for that, you can try to paste that in the source but I'm not sure: 'http://vocaroo.com/player.swf?playMediaID=s1JRqxYv6jN1&autoplay=0'

Comment: so what i need to do ?

Comment: It's not really a programming question less than finding a tool, I can't really help you on that.